# [Azure AD]: User Group Assign Owner

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I was Working in Azure Ad. i have to create a users and Group and Mapping user into group using Graph API.but, I could't find the How to assign the Owner in User Group using Graph API.

Any API's Available for assign the Group Owner in Azure Using Graph API

Anyone Know Share the Link.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this one you will have to use Microsoft Graph API, I couldn't find a way to do this in Azure AD Graph API.

You are looking for this operation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_owners

Make an HTTP POST request to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners/$ref` (replace {id} with the group's object id) with a request body like:

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
}
```

*Replace {id} with the user's object id*.

Comment: Thanks juunas. It's Working for me. and i was know little bit about Microsoft Graph API and Azure AD Graph API and when and which place are use the requests.